# Disable visual editors in MyEclipse

Tags: eclipse, myeclipse

What is the best way to disable all visual editors in MyEclipse?

Every time I open an HTML file, it spends a few seconds to render the HTML file in a wysiwyg editor and fails at it.
Every time I open a properties files, it opens it in a excel-like table that completely ignores the comments in the properties files.

The first thing I do is to hide the visual panel to revert to the source code.

I never use a wysiwyg editor or any design wizard.  But I can only change file associations one type at a time.  For HTML I have to change the assotiation for .html, .htm and .xhtml.  Same for the various .xml files.

Isn't there a way to remove or disable all visual editors for good, so that MyEclipse doesn't spend time and memory on it?  Maybe even uninstall them?

Answer (score 1):

```
Right clic on File > Open With > text editor
```

After doing that for a file, eclipse keep this as default for the file

or in preferences, in `General > Editors > File Associations` set for every extension the text editor associate to it (but like you said, you have to do it for every extension, but it doesn't take so much time to do it and once you've set it, it's remembered)

Comment: Thanks. As you said, the default is for the file, not all files with the same extension.  And the file association reverts every time you reinstall MyEclipse.  I am still searching for a more global solution.

Comment: if you want to keep it after reinstalling MyEclipse, then have the workspace location outside MyEclipse, therefore preferences will be kept (assuming MyEclipse allows you to select a workspace)